# How to get button information and pass to another PHP page?

Tags: php

I want to get the information from this formwhen you press the add to cart button. and i want to use that information in a cart page.

```
<?php
  $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query); 
  $output = '';

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $output .= '
 <div style="margin-bottom: 20px;" class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
  <form method="post ">
    <div style="height: 400px;" class="card shadow text-center">
      <div class="card-block shop-item">
        <img class="shop-item-image" src="Bilder/clothes/'. $row['ProductImage'].'" alt="" class="img-fluid" style="height: 200px;">
        <div class="card-text shop-item-title">
          '.$row['Brand'].'
        </div>
        <div class="card-text">

          '.$row['Quantity'].' in stock
        </div>
        <div class="shop-item-details">
          <div class="card-text" shop-item-price>
            <h3>£ '.$row['Price'].'</h3>
          </div>
          <input style="width: 80%; margin-left: 10%; " type="text" name="quantity" class="form-control" value="1"/>
          <button style="margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px; background-color:#FB8122; border: none; color:black;"href="#" class="shop-item-button btn btn-primary ">Add to cart <span class="fas fa-cart-arrow-down"></span></button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>;';
}

 echo $output;
}

?>
```

First time asking so sorry if I did something wrong

Comment: Please format your code properly. Remove the backticks around the code and make sure that you've posted _all_ the code. It looks like you're missing a `while` before `($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))`

Comment: If you want to post that form to some other page, then you need to add an `action`-attribute to your form: `action="/path/to/file.php"`.

Comment: You can save the cart content as a session.